# Unsure about the usage of Past Perfect Continuous in a specific sentence

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

Is it correct to use the Past Perfect Continuous form *I had never been considering*

in the sentence

> Before I met you, I had never been considering visiting Italy

?

According to [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/past-perfect-continuous-tense/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAjJOQBhCkARIsAEKMtO03J9VMxPFK9dmd_-vRTAF7B6J0szN4Ll33Cs_q4l66zlJB_0WHwQgaAr7bEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds),

> The past perfect continuous tense (also known as the past perfect
> progressive tense) shows that an action that started in the past
> continued up until another time in the past

Thus, if *not considering something* is an action, it is correct to use the Past Perfect Continuous here, since it started before and ended at the point when the two met, which happened in the past. But it just sounds so weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- *Before I met you, I had never considered visiting Italy* and
- *Before I met you, I wasn't
  considering visiting Italy*

sound far more idiomatic.

In fact, the 'I had never been V-ing' string only works, I'd say, with phase structures (the 'go shopping' structure):

- *I had never been fishing / hunting / dancing  ... before I met Peter.*